# How to pause boot messages on ubuntu installer?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install ubuntu 19.04 on a brand-new PC configuration, from a bootable USB stick created with rufus.

I've encountered an issue: the usb regularly boots, but when GRUB 2.0 prompts me with choosing among installing ubuntu, trying without installing, OEM install etc., whatever my choice (except "check disk for errors"), it gets stuck on the purple splash screen with the animated dots.
I tried to check disk for errors, and it reports none, so I pressed ESC to check the debug boot messages, and I see a bunch of [FAILURE]. Basically, everything on screen is a [FAILURE], but I can't scroll up to read what's the first failure that cascaded the others.
I tried to run the installer without the "quiet" and "splash" options (by pressing 'e' in GRUB and removing the options), but still it's scrolling too fast to let me read what the problem is.

Is there any way to pause the scrolling of boot messages, or have a behavior like the 'more' command in linux? How am I supposed to debug the problem, if I can't actually read the debug log?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try typing `Ctrl-S` to pause, and `Ctrl-Q` to resume. Or you could use a cellphone camera.

Comment: sorry, that didn't work out